# How using JQuery to hide/show next <div> element by clicking on the <a> element, change the value of <a> and flip the icon that has its background?

Tags: jquery

There is such a generated markup, where the icon is made as the background of the `<a>` tag and placed next to the value of this tag:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="header-title" style="
    background-image: url(/path);
    background-position: right;
    height: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 25px;">
Hide design</a>
  <div class="field-design"></div>
</div>
```

I need to click on `<a>` to hide the `<div class="field-design"></div>` and change the value of `<a>` from Hide Design to Show Design. When I click again, do the opposite. How can this be implemented?
[image]

Comment: Use `$(this).next()` to get the next element after the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply all these and it will work.

```js
 $('.header-title').click(function(){
  // changing the text inside the anchor tag
  $(this).html("Show Design");
  // changing the icon of the anchor tag
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/new-path)');
  // show or hide next div element
  $('.header-title + div').toggleClass('d-none');
})
```

```css
/*For showing and hiding div element*/
.d-none{
  display: none;
}
```